NeMo-Guardrails Strange requirement for 'user_query'
I'm trying to reproduce Hello , World case in here
But with twist when I am tryin to get output with Python code.
According the response I need to define 'user_query' .
Why and how I can define 'user_query' ? I am just need to get output from openai model.
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
new_message = rails.generate(messages=[{
"role": "user",
"content": "Hello! What can you do for me?"
}])
new_message
Output :
{'role': 'assistant', 'content': "Action 'user_query' not found."}

Some cache held old version of .co file with action.
I was able to resolve the issue to put my files to new folder or using config = RailsConfig.from_content that looks me even better solution to make coding more convenient.
